# Cart page Summary section

Tags: magento2

In Cart page , Summary Section is there know , in that shipping flat rate will be 5. so i want to add static amount 10. so whenever i will go to cart page shipping rate will be 5+10 = 15 .
So how i can achieve this? I want to use only observer. Can anyone please help me to do this.

getEvent()->getQuote();
        $quote->setShippingAmount(10);
        $quote->save();
       
    
    }
}

I have used this code. but i didnt get.


Thanks

Comment: Please describe what you are trying to do?

Comment: I want to set shipping amount in magento2 , while going to cart page

Comment: Please share solutions for this, thanks